# System.EnterpriseServices.RegistrationHelper - execute as x64 or x86

Tags: .net, com

System.EnterpriseServices.RegistrationHelper is the programmatically the same as regsvcs.

But is it possible to call specific (32 or 64bit) version of helper? With one registration (Server or Library) we want one  version (32 or 64) of registration, with another - another.

Is there any way to specify needed deploying type?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229076(VS.80).aspx